# How to change the color of the stars for primeng p-rating

Tags: css, angular

I am new to Angular and I do have a problem with the styling of the rating stars of p-rating from the priming module.

[image: Here is an image of the default p-rating component]

I tried to work with the information provided by primeNG but was not successful in changing the star color at all. The only thing I could achieve was changing the background-color of the p-rating container.

[Here is the link to the primeNG rating-module](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/rating)

The given styling informations by the documentation did not help me at all.

Does anyone know how to change the color of the stars to let's say orange?
If that's the case, how do I do it?

Comment: Thanks to everyone for correcting my question. I'll try to do it better next time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this style should change the starts color

```
.ui-rating a {
    color: blue !important;
}
```

change blue for whatever color you want;